# HQL : select sum group by join

Tags: hibernate, hql

In HQL I would make a query like this :
I want to select the category name and the sum montantdebit by a category

```
category{ idcategory ;namecategory}
```

and

```
 operation {montantdebit , Category}
```

I have tried the following:

```
select cat.nameCategory, sum(operation.montantdebit)  from Operation operation join  operation.category  cat group  by cat.idCategory
```

I got thie error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:242) ~[spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225) ~[spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527) ~[spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

- Could you provide more details like no of tables, and columns in the
  table.
- Or you can refer the query given below:

  > Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee");
  >
  > query = session.createQuery("select    e.name, sum(e.salary),
  >   count(e)"
  >                         + " from Employee e where e.name like '%i%' group by e.name");
- Or you can refer the following source:
  https://www.journaldev.com/2954/hibernate-query-language-hql-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Two things to fix in your query:

1. You must include in your `GROUP BY` clause, the field nameCategory
2. You can exclude the `JOIN` clause because `Category` object is an object encapsulated in your `Operation` object

You must write your query as follow:

```
SELECT operation.category.nameCategory, sum(operation.montantdebit) 
FROM Operation operation
GROUP BY operation.category.idCategory, operation.category.nameCategory
```

Comment: thanks , i tried this but it's not work ..the same error

Comment: @ELHassane:I've updated my answer using category as field of operation (instead of cat). Che the name I've used (idCategory and nameCategory)